# Mapping surroundings

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Who know one program that voluntarily move on in strange environment, then give me a map of surroundings. It very like SLAM+navigation. I want to find the program that with this function. Can you help me?
Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238773/mapping-surroundings/) by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hope this package will help:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_exploration_3d

It is an implementation of autonomous mapping with a turtlebot equipped with Kinect sensor.

---

Originally posted by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) with karma: 101 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0